# Does using number type instead of string speed up performance in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Since CouchDb stores document in json format and views are indexed after each document change. Do I get more performance if use number instead of string if possible?

Currently I'm using

```
string type
string syncedToSQL
string epidemicFrom
string group
string year
string app
```

What I can do is :

```
number type
number syncedToSQL
string epidemicFrom --remains as string
number group
number year
number app
```

The views are took using `group, year, app, type` fields.

Comment: This probably calls for a benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The influence of using number types will probably be negligible on performance (I guess you are talking about read performance). Try optimizing the views themselves if necessary. All in all, performance and possible optimizations depend on your exact use case (how many documents, what storage devices do you have, what are your needs and expectations for performance vs. readability).

I'd suggest you should starti out with a simple, readable solution and some performance benchmarks, then try to change the year property to number (you don't have to abstract there, because the year is inherently numeric). If your benchmarks deliver performance benefits, change the other types, but I doubt it is worth the effort, and it increases complexity if you encode types, groups and apps numerically.

If you need those types of optimizations, consider using a SQL database as an alternative.